# How to show $\operatorname{codim}(\operatorname{Ker} f)=1$ if f is linear?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let L be linear space and $f :L\to \Bbb R(\Bbb C)$ is linear
>   functional. $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker} \DeclareMathOperator{\codim}{codim}$ $\Ker f$ is a linear subspace and $\codim(\Ker f)=1$

$\Ker f:=\{x:x\in L, f(x)=0\}$
since $f(ax+by)=0$ (for all a,b scalar) $ax+by\in \Ker f$. $\Ker f$ is linear subspace.

since $f$ isn't equal to 0, we can write $f(x_o)=1$. (otherwise we can take $\frac {x_o}{f(x_o)}$ instead of $x_o$)

for any $x\in L$,  $f(x-f(x)x_o)=f(x)-f(x)f(x_p)=f(x)-f(x)=0$

so $x-f(x)x_o\in \Ker f$. then there is $y_x\in \Ker f$ st. $x=f(x)x_o+y_x$.

we should show if $L^\sim\in L/\Ker f$ then  for all $x\in L^\sim$ there are $\alpha_L^\sim$ scalars st $f(x)=\alpha_L^\sim$

assuming $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ st $x_1,x_2\in L^\sim$. then

$x_1=f(x_1)x_o+y_{x_1}$

$x_2=f(x_2)x_o+y_{x_2}$

How to continue ? how do we find the contradiction.

Comment: I think you have basically showed your claim.  By your second line you have shown that if $x_0$ is not in the kernel, then any element $x \in L$ is equivalent to an element in the span of $x_0$, mod the kernel.  Therefore the codimension is $1$.  No?

Comment: Regarding your actual question though, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the same equivalence class then $x_1 - x_2$ is in the kernel, so $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ necessarily.

Comment: I improved the $\LaTeX$ markup of your question, please look at how I did it so that you may improve your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, just to be sure, are you trying to show that for every finite dimension vector space X a linear functional kernel dimension is n-1? (if dimX=n)

if that so, then you can use the fact that dimKerf+dimImf=dimX

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: The first part should be an answer, but the problem is sufficiently simple that the second part is enough to be a full answer.

Comment: vincent, i would write it as a comment but since i just joined this site today i dont have sufficient reputation to comment something that i did not post... and i do believe that i have provided the answer. or at list most of it